# How to pipe window function output directly into a new window function in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, common-table-expression, window-functions

I am new to SQL and I have the following query:

```
-- Ref 1
SELECT *,
Max(Watts) OVER (PARTITION BY Freq) as MyMax,
log10(SUM(MyMax) OVER SumFunct * 1000) * 10 AS MySum
FROM MyTable
WINDOW SumFunct as (PARTITION BY temp, Freq, channel);
```

This doesn't work due to `no such column: MyMax`. Even though from my understanding the column for `MyMax` is being created on the fly, I'm guessing SQL still isn't able to use its values immediately as an input into the next window function

I already tried creating the column for MaxPower and populating it prior to the query above, via

```
-- Ref 2
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN MyMax real;
UPDATE MyTable SET MyMax = sub.MyMax 
FROM (
   SELECT *, Max(Watts) OVER (PARTITION BY Freq) AS MyMax
) sub;
```

But I don't know how to set `MyMax` with a window function within an `UPDATE` statement. My attempt at this was to create a sub-query but I feel like I was overcomplicating the problem and I also didn't get this working due to some syntax at the `SELECT` I couldn't isolate.

All I want to do is query `MyMax` using the window function above, and essentially pipe it into a new window function. The result: two extra columns with the data I need. My understanding of window functions is that they will create the column you want on the fly, but even when I break apart the top query (Ref 1) into two different calls:

```
-- Ref3
SELECT *,
Max(Watts) OVER (PARTITION BY Freq) as MyMax,
FROM MyTable;
SELECT *,
log10(SUM(MyMax) OVER SumFunct * 1000) * 10 AS MySum
FROM MyTable
WINDOW SumFunct as (PARTITION BY temp, Freq, channel);
```

It still doesn't recognize what `MyMax` is. Does anyone have any guidance on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting of window functions is not allowed.

You need a subquery that returns `MyMax` and the main query to return `MySum`:

```
SELECT *, log10(SUM(MyMax) OVER SumFunct * 1000) * 10 AS MySum
FROM (
  SELECT *, Max(Watts) OVER (PARTITION BY Freq) AS MyMax
  FROM MyTable
)
WINDOW SumFunct as (PARTITION BY temp, Freq, channel);
```

Or, a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, Max(Watts) OVER (PARTITION BY Freq) as MyMax
  FROM MyTable
)
SELECT *, log10(SUM(MyMax) OVER SumFunct * 1000) * 10 AS MySum
FROM cte
WINDOW SumFunct as (PARTITION BY temp, Freq, channel);
```